# Laravel Envoy can't detect node/npm on Ubuntu when installed with NVM (node version manager) bash: line 5: npm: command not found

Tags: node.js, linux, laravel, npm, laravel-envoy

I've installed node/npm with NVM on Ubuntu 18.04. I can ssh into the server and run `node -v` (v13.9.0) and `npm -v` (v13.9.0), so they are installed and are executable by the user.

When I try and do this via the Laravel Envoy deploy tool I get the following error:

`bash: line 5: npm: command not found`

My Envoy script is super simple like so:

```
@servers(['main' => ['deploy@**.***.**.**']])

@task('deploy', ['on' => 'main'])
    composer -V
    npm -v
@endtask
```

So for some reason when Envoy logs into the server it doesn't have access to node/npm. Everything else installed on the system such as php and composer works fine.

Is there any reason that Envoy can't see the NVM node/npm install? Is Envoy not logging in with my deploy user?

---

When I check which npm it points to:

`/home/deploy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.9.0/bin/npm`

I've tried calling this directly in my ssh shell and get the correct result, npm runs as expected.

I then tried adding this to my Envoy script like so:

```
@task('deploy', ['on' => 'main'])
    composer -V
    /home/deploy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.9.0/bin/node -v
@endtask
```

However it returns the error:

`‘node’: No such file or directory`

Interestingly I can run node using Laravel Envoy by directly referencing the binary like so `/home/deploy/.nvm/versions/node/v13.9.0/bin/node -v`

Comment: I'm having the same issue with getting Envoyer to use nvm, despite having installed nvm directly on the VPS as the user `forge` (the Envoyer user as well). Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem where running `nvm use` I got same error `command not found`. Seems like nvm is not activated from the profile files (e.g. ~/.bashrc). I looked at the nvm [README](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#install--update-script) and just copied source lines to my Envoy script.

```
@task('deploy')
    export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
    [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
    nvm use # Now works!
@endtask
```